# Cant properly UV unwrap a wood texture - its skewed (newbie alert)

Tags: uv

So I have a cube that I tapered one one end it has a subdivision modifier on it, with some additional edge loops and the left and right side sections extruded out just a bit.

I used smart uv project, which seemed to unwrap the UV's nicely from the UV editor however the texture (wood image texture) seems to be all skewed and for the life of me I can't figure out what I did wrong or how to fix it.  I have spent a lot of time on tutorials for UV stuff but its not clicking or I did something really dumb.

Here is a screenshot of what Im talking about.

[image]

It sorta looks ok with a UV texture applied.. the squares for the most of the part look ok outside of the edges where I did some extrusion.

[image]

any advice outside of stop uv editing would be appreciated :) lol..

Cheers!

Comment: Could you share your Material Node screen or if possible, your file, so some can take a look at it

Comment: So, I decided to rebuilt the material.. and for whatever reason the problem went away.. I did originally have some mapping (scaling) to the texture node but remove that.. I wonder if it still kept that even though it was deleted.. uggg.. spent way to much time on this :)